# Force android media player to complete playback before start again

Tags: java, android, android-mediaplayer, android-sensors

I'm making an app that uses the accelerometer and when it detects a shake motion it plays a sound from the raw folder. My problem is that if the sound is not finished and a new shake motion i detected it will trigger the sound again and the previous one will be canceled. I want the previous sound file to be completed before the new one can be played. How can i achive this? Should it be done in the sensor or the play class? 
This is the class that takes a resid and then start the media player.

```
public void Play(final int resid) {

    Log.d(TAG, "i Play(med resid)");
    if (mp != null && mp.isPlaying()) { //ta bort isplaying
        Log.v(TAG, "Reset");
        mp.reset();
        Log.v(TAG, "Release");
        mp.release();
    }
    if (resid == 0) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Choose an instrument", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    } else {

        Log.d(TAG,"Now playing!");
        mp = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), resid);
        mp.start();
        int duration = mp.getDuration();
        Log.v(TAG, "Length: " + duration);
    }

}
```

This is one of the sensors

```
  public void TiltingSensor(SensorEvent event, int resid) {
    Sensor mSensor = event.sensor;
    if (mSensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER) {
        float x_axis = event.values[0];
        float y_axis = event.values[1];

        if ((x_axis < 9.80 && x_axis > 0.50) && (y_axis > -9 && y_axis < 0 )){
            //Log.d("Angles", Float.toString(x_axis) + "   Y:  " + Float.toString(y_axis));
            Play(resid);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's you who are restarting player:

```
if (mp != null && mp.isPlaying()) { //ta bort isplaying
    Log.v(TAG, "Reset");
    mp.reset();
    Log.v(TAG, "Release");
    mp.release();
}
```

Try changing the code to:

```
if (mp != null && mp.isPlaying()) {
    Log.v(TAG, "Already playing");
    return;
} else if (mp != null) { // it's better to release player
    Log.v(TAG, "Release");
    mp.release();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to start the music second time when the motion is detected while playing the first time, then use a incremental reference count in Play() before return if media player returns true for isPlaying().
Then in oncompletionListener(), decrement the reference count and post a message to invoke Play() again.